# How to return data from two mysql tables as one info

Tags: mysql

I have two tables a & b, a is used for old data and be for new/current data, but when giving a report the total count should include even data from the old data table a. That is i can have a row of data say x in table a which is not found in table b and vice versa. In any case there is no data in either, then the data found in the one table containing data is what is brought back, and incase both tables have duplicate data only one is brought back based on the labref. (the tables are joined)

Suggestion

```
example (both data is existing)

table a                      table b 
---------                  ------------
labref  username            labref  username
x        Alphy                j      Alphy
y        John                 k      Ken
```

example (data is existing in one table)

```
table a                      table b 
---------                  ------------
labref  username            labref  username
x        Alphy                     
y        John
```

Comment: I think you can try UNION

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a `union`:

```
select labref,username from tableA
union
select labref,username from tableB
```